# Modifying factory objects with checkboxes in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a phonebook app. I have contacts some of which have "favourite" boolean value. My contacts come from a factory. When I click on a name from the list of contacts in my app, I get the contact details partial on the right. So it looks like this:

Contact list:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="showDetails(person)">
...
```

Main controller (OK here already I feel that this is not the best way of doing it.):

```
var selectedPersonName = null;

$scope.showDetails = function(person){
    $scope.selectedPersonName = person.name;
    $scope.selectedPersonCity = person.city;
}
```

Contact details partial:

```
<span ng-show="selectedPersonName == null">Select contact</span>

<ul class = "contact-details" ng-hide="selectedPersonName == null">
    <li>{{selectedPersonName}}</li>
    <li>{{selectedPersonCity}}</li>
</ul>
```

I would also like to display the checkbox which would change the Friend status, whether is is checked or unchecked. I have tried several variants, but although I did manage to get my checkbox display the actual true/false status of the object, none of them change the object state on click. I would appreciate any comments and advice on the current um 'architecture' of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot: ([Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WrK3UzIe5AlhekiCtF1h?p=preview))

HTML:

```
<span ng-show="!selectedPerson">Select contact</span>

<ul class = "contact-details" ng-hide="!selectedPerson">
    <li>{{selectedPerson.name}}</li>
    <li>{{selectedPerson.city}}</li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedPerson.favorite"> Favorite
      </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.showDetails = function(person){
    $scope.selectedPerson = person;
}
```

Basically you just need to use ng-model to set up two-way binding between the checkbox and the favorite state.

Comment: Very nice! Great solution, thanks! Exactly, was puzzled with 2-way binding.